# How to create a placeholder for empty factor levels on a bar chart axis using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, axis

I have some survey data, from which I would like to simply graph the frequency of each response per question.

My code

```
library(ggplot2)

Df1 # data frame with 3 variables: Provider, Question, Score

Df1$Score <- factor(Df1$Score, levels = c(0,1,2,3))

# Plot
q <- qplot(Score, data = Df1, facets = .~Provider, geom="bar", fill=Provider)

q + labs(title = wrapper(Question, width = 70), x = "Score", y = "Frequency")   # Add title and axes labels
```

And the result is this:
[image]

Which is great but as I will be generating a few of these graphs, it would visually easier to interpret if there was a space for '1' on the x-axis too.

I have spent a lot of time trying various combinations `scale_x_discrete`, `labels`, `breaks` and `reorder` but I've still not been able to generate an elusive placeholder.

Is there an easy way to force ggplot2 to plot an empty factor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a full reproducible example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, 
            aes(factor(gear, levels = 1:5), 
                mpg)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_discrete(drop=F)
```

Use `drop=FALSE` to keep unused factor levels.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `limits` parameter in the `scale_x_discrete` function to hold the place, here is a dummy example:

```
df
  month count
1   Jan     1
2   Feb     2
3   Mar     3
ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = count)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
       scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"))
```

[image]